# Facebook apps acting as plugins

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

Quick question, is it possible to write an app for facebook that is plugin esque? For example, could I have my app change the facebook logo or add a new ding sound on a new message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

What you are talking about is a browser plugin or user script.  Facebook applications don't deal with the Facebook interface at all...

Comment: cool is there any sort of resource that I can look at to teach me how to make a plugin that would work like a facebook plugin?

Comment: Thats kind of a broad question.  Google will be able to help you getting started with your first browser plugin...

Comment: hey look we got a comedian here

Comment: @A.Collins - I don't appreciate your cynicism... If you were to glance at the [faq] of this site, you'll see that questions need to be `"practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"`.  Open ended, broad questions tend to solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion and that's not what we are looking for on [so].

Comment: Why don't you attempt to get your first extension up and running and if/when you come across a specific problem, come post about it...